# Solutions of $\frac{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor(1 + \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)}{2 n} = \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor(1 + \lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor)}{2 k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Testing the

$$\frac{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor(1 + \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)}{2 n} = \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor(1 + \lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor)}{2 k}$$

And found that for Oblong numbers (numbers of form $(n+1)n$) this equation is true. In other words this equation has infint solutions for those numbers. While for other ones just has discovered that it has finite solutions (experiment).

Trying to prove the last statement.

Comment: More precisely, define $\,a(n) := \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor(1 + \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)}{2 n}.\,$ Then $\,a(n)=x\,$ has infinite solutions given by oblong numbers if $\,x=1/2\,$ while it has only finite number of solutions otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t$ be a fixed number not equal to $1$.For $$\frac{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor(1 + \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)}{ n} = t$$ we require there to be an integer $k$ such that $$k^2\le n<(k+1)^2, k(k+1)=nt.$$
Then $$\frac{k}{k+1}\le\frac{1}{t}<\frac{k+1}{k}.$$

As $k$ tends to infinity, $\frac{k}{k+1}$ and $\frac{k+1}{k}$ both tend to $1$ and so only finitely many $k$ can satisfy the equations. Therefore there are only finitely many $n=\frac{k(k+1)}{t}$.

Comment: So for the case $t=1$ we get the Oblong numbers, right?